# SSRS overlapping column chart

Tags: charts, reporting-services

currently i have the following chart: 
[image]

It currently contains one column (blue one) and a range column (white one). But what i really need is a chart which looks like the following:

[image]

So the white column should be overlapped by the blue column. I tried to change the range column to a normal column and changed the "CustomAttribute" PointWidth but was not able to get my chart looking like the needed chart.

Does somebody knows how to do that? Thanks

---

@glh: I know that, it currently looks like this (changing the white range to column):
 [image]

*ANGEFALLEN* = blue column
*EINGEPLANTV1* = white column

Problem is that the white column is now right to the blue column.
[image]

If i change the order of the chart data the blue column ins right to the white column. But i need the white column to be behind the blue column like shown in the second picture of the main post / question.

**Followup 25.04.2013:**

The chart should look like this:
[image]

I need to **move** 1/3 of the white column behind the blue column so that 2/3 of the white column is still visible. The blue column has to be in the foreground and the white column in the background.

Comment: You'll need to change the order of your data x axis values. What does your values, category and series structure look like? Do you have 3 sets of values and no index?

Comment: X-Axis Values: 1. the blue column 2. the white column. Category is a little bit different. It depends on what you choose in the parameters. You have the possibility to change the grouping by setting the specific report parameter.

Answer (score 3):

**Overlapping Series:**

Change the "overlapping" series to a "Range Column" chart type. This will allow you to layer the two series on top of each other.

Once you do this, you will notice that the series will get two value drop-downs:

[image: Range Column Series with multiple value drop-downs]

Set the "Low" drop down to an expression with the value of 0.

Set the "High" drop down to the value you would like to represent.

**Offset Series Position:**

I am actually not sure if this is possible in SSRS. However, you can play with the widths of the layered series to achieve a similar effect.

[image: Series Column Width]

Set the PointWidth propety of the series (under CustomAttributes) either larger or smaller than the default .08, depending on your desired effect.

Here is a quick mockup I put together. It isn't exactly what you were looking for, but maybe it'll get your creative brain juices flowing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to drag the values around in the values box or there will be a blue up or down arrow to alter the order your data is displayed. See below for an example of what you will see when you select the charts data.

[image]

Comment: Dragged the values back and forth - changed the color, changed the referenced data etcetera. I think it is not clear what i really need. The data of both columns (blue and white column) are correct. The only thing i want to change is **the way they are displayed**. At the moment the both columns are next to each other like posted in my question. Now i need to **move** 1/3 of the white column behind the blue column so that 2/3 of the white column is still visible. The blue column has to be in the foreground and the white column in the background.

Comment: The above will change the order to which data is in front you may need to re-jig the colours. Based on your initial question you could alter colour and overlap the columns.

Comment: When re-ordering the columns the only thing that changes is that the blue column is left and the white column right and vice versa when re ordering. I cant get one column **behind** the other column like i want it to have :(

Comment: I see. I thought you had? I'll look into it some more.

Comment: May be you can change one to a secondary x axis and mess with the formatting?